# Can Nero SecurDisc Surface Scan be rerun after the disc had been burned?

Tags: burning, blu-ray, data-integrity, nero

I burned a double layered BD-R disc (UDF file system), it finished successfully then in the midst of the surface scan run I had a power outage before it had the time to finish.

All of the data was MP4 videos.
Can the original files (on the SSD) be corrupted?

Can the surface scan be rerun in some way?
If not, what are my best alternatives in order to not waste a new disk?

Is fc.exe /b (binary compare) a good idea?

or

Using Get-FileHash in powershell to compare files hashes?

Comment: Did the burn finish? The only way to know if the data on the disk is good is to read it.

Comment: It did, since the scan process doesn't begin until the disc is burned successfully, the problem I had in the past is discs burned successfully (sometimes files even readable) yet the surface scan failing.